# Hide content in DIV while expanding container and playing a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I've seen it done but can't at the moment find the site.

I have a hero image with a play button and when it's clicked I'd like to hide the content of that div while expanding it then fading in a video.

I'm using the  tag to absolutely position the embedded the video behind the hero copy.

I can do the CSS of transitioning the container and fading everything but I'm too novice with jquery to setup the scripting of it.

You can see what I have so far @ http://www.gigyastaging.com/

Currently video is overlaid and plays automatically, can I stop it from pre-loading and only load the video when the play button is clicked?

Comment: to remove the autoplay try removing the "autoplay" attr from video element and you forgot to close the video tag. btw i like the site design ;)

Comment: Fixed those two issues- thanks for that. Thanks for the like as well :D

Comment: are you looking to do something like this? `$('#hero-play').on('click', function(){
 $(this).fadeOut();
 $('.slider-inner').append('<video id="video_background" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/84613377.hd.mp4?s=7820d9cd4d5b295c7f289492772afb90" style="display: none;"></video>');
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `autoplay` attribute:

```
<video id="video_background" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/84613377.hd.mp4?s=7820d9cd4d5b295c7f289492772afb90"></video>
```

Next, hide the video from the user:

```
<video id="video_background" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/84613377.hd.mp4?s=7820d9cd4d5b295c7f289492772afb90" style="display: none;"></video>
```

Now make some simple js code to listen for a click, fade the video in, play it, and finally fade out when the video has finished.

```
$("video").on("ended", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$("#hero-play").click(function(){
   var v = $("video");

   v.fadeIn();
   v.get(0).play();
});
```

You may notice how I use `v.get(0)`.  This is because jQuery doesn't have a way to play the video, you need to get the raw DOM element and then call the `play` method belonging to the video element.

Simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yKum/2/) example.

Comment: Worked like a charm! People like you make me love the webz!

Comment: Perhaps you can help with this.. on the same site, gigyastaging.com I'm trying to get a "finish" listener to work. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly but it's not working. I essentially want to hide the video play and change everything back to normal once the video completes.

Comment: @CameronCunningham If you look at the available [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FMedia_events), you will see an event called `ended`.  All you have to do is subscribe to it and fade the video out when it is triggered.  I have  edited my answer and fiddle to show an example.